# Band limits of solids

Tags: condensed-matter, electronic-band-theory

Did the valence band and conduction band really extends upto infinity? Why i am asking this is, because the books use this to find concentration of electrons and holes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as far as I know the answer is no: the bands have upper and lower bounds and the typical bandwidth is of the same order as the Fermi energy $E_F$. However, the typical temperature $T$ that we are interested in is much less than the Fermi temperature, so $k_BT \ll E_F$ and hence it is very unlikely that the electrons populate states with very high energy and for some purposes you can approximate the band as unbound.
How good this approximation is depends on the specific problem I guess.

Comment: This sounds correct in the case of an elementary discussion.  When first approached, solids are treated as infinite in all directions (or pedantically as a large 3-torus, as periodic boundary conditions are used.).  I would guess that a surface or interface of some kind would be needed to give the bands an upper bound, or extend them into the continuum where they eventually lose identity.